# Find a function $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with some conditions

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Find a function $f :\mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying that :
$$f(1)=1$$
$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+2xy$$
$$f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{f(x)}{x^4} \hspace{5pt}\forall x \neq 0$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $$(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2+2xy{}$$

Answer (score 0):

I do to here :
let $g(x)=f(x)-x^2$ , at that time :
$$g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$$
$$g(1)=g(0)=0$$
$$g(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{g(x)}{x^{4}}$$

I proved $g(x)\equiv 0$ with $ x \in \mathbb{Q}$ but proving $g(x) \equiv 0$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is problem for me, can you help me more

Comment: If $f$ is taken to be continuous then by the fact it is $0$ on $\mathbb Q$ it has to be zero everywhere.

Comment: We can't say we must prove

Comment: But you are supposed to find a function and prove it has the properties. Simply prove that $f(x)=x^2$ has the wanted properties and you're done. I don't see why you need to do this.

Comment: Example we don't have $f(\sqrt{2})=0$ we just have $f(x)=0$ with $\forall x \in Q$

Comment: I don't understand. You are supposed to *find* a function with the properties mentioned in your question. So you are supposed to find a function and then prove that the properties hold for it. Simply say "Let us take $f(x)=x^2$, and we will see that the properties hold..." or something like that. Furthermore without assumption of continuity you cannot possible deduce that $f(q)=0$ for all $q\in\mathbb Q$ implies $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Take for example $$h(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x\in\mathbb Q\\1& x\notin\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$

Comment: @LevanDokite So you proved that $f(x)=x^2 , \ x \in \mathbb{R}$ has the wanted properties. If you want to know if this $f$ is unique with the above properties maybe you should ask another question.

Comment: Consider any $ x \ne 0 $. For any nonzero rational $ y $ with $ y \ne x $, note that
$$ g \left( \frac 1 { x - y } \right) - g \left( \frac 1 x \right) = y g \left( \frac 1 { x ( x - y ) } \right) $$
by additivity. Use the other condition and simplify the above equation to get
$$ g \left( x ^ 2 \right) = \left( 4 x ^ 3 - 6 x ^ 2 y + 4 x y ^ 2 - y ^ 3 + y \right) g ( x ) \text . $$
Now, if $ g ( x ) \ne 0 $, the LHS will be constant WRT $ y $, while the RHS won't, a contradiction. Thus $ g ( x ) = 0 $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. Therefore, $ f ( x ) = x ^ 2 $ is the only solution.